# Python subprocess issue on Windows

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to write a Python script to convert a bunch of images.

It's something like the following code (after a huge minimization):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from subprocess import call

cmd = ' '.join(['convert.exe', '-resize', '110', 'foo\\a.jpg', 'bar\\a.jpg'])
print cmd
call(cmd)
```

I get the error below after executing it:

```
Parameter not valid - 110
```

While when I copy / paste the string emitted from the script on the command line the image convertion works perfectly.
What did I miss?

Comment: Is '-resize 110', all one parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the error is most likely the result of two things

1. In the call command, try using `shell=True` as the second argument.
2. You're using relative paths, and the working directory might not be the same for python as it is from your cmd shell.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the convert.exe your script is calling is the same one you are calling from the command line. I have, out of bitter experience, always used the full path to the executable I want to call from a script, Python or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP has a command shell command named convert. When I feed it your command, I get the same error message you're seeing. I suspect it is being called instead of your convert.exe.